# FCC Chunky Monkey Recursive

Tags: javascript, recursion

I just finished the Chunky Monkey Excercise on FCC and whilst I was looking to improve my solution, I chanced upon an alternate model that used recursion.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var mArr = [];

  function newChunks (arr, size, mArr){
    if (arr.length > 0 ){
      mArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
      newChunks(arr, size, mArr);
    }

  }
  newChunks(arr, size, mArr);
  return mArr;
}
```

I understand the first section of it but the last part is a little confusing to me. Why is newChunks called again?

```
newChunks(arr, size, mArr);
      return mArr;
    }
```

I tried playing around with the code by removing newChunks and simply returning mArr but all that was returned was [].

Any clarification would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: What is the exercise?

Comment: `newChunks(arr, size, mArr);` is the initiating point

Comment: @Aron, Chunky Monkey!

Answer (score 0):

> Why is newChunks called again?

It's not called *again* at the end. Without the call at the end, it would never be called at all, because the only other call to it is a recursive one (a call where it calls itself). The call at the end is what starts the recursive process.

When `newChunks` is called, if the passed-in array has at least one entry, it removes a chunk and pushes that onto `myArr`. Then it calls itself in case there are more chunks to do.

---

Side note: That implementation *modifies* the array it's given (specifically, it empties it out, because it's using `splice`, which is a mutator method). Normally, a function like `newChunks` should leave the input array alone.

Here's a solution that, like that one, avoids creating unnecessary arrays but doesn't modify the original:

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  function worker(index, source, dest, size) {
    if (index < source.length) {
      dest.push(source.slice(index, index + size));
      worker(index + size, source, dest, size);
    }
  }
  
  var result = [];
  worker(0, arr, result, size);
  return result;
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunkArrayInGroups(a, 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: So index in this case would refer to the location of the element in the array that is currently being examined by the function? 

Correct me if I'm wrong but this is my understanding so far
1. The function takes in arr and the specified size of each nested array
2. It then creates an empty array called result
3. The function worker is then called to create the end product
4. It starts at the first element of index zero, runs and then calls itself again if there are still elements because the index of the element will always be less than the length.
5. This continues till desired result.

Comment: @IvanLeo: Perfect! (And when it calls itself, it passes itself an updated `index`.)